# How to print a document file to a network printer in c#

Tags: c#, printing, network-printers

I need to send files (txt, docs etc.) over network using printer driver. I'm able to send raw data to server but not files. I had already tried to [Ehsan's Method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11684469/17768086) for printing, but the data inside the document doesn't seems to appear in the document. What I need is a method, or `cmd` line to print a file over network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, could you please give me a clue which type of file you want to print if it is a text file. it's quite simple you drag two component from the tool box first the `printDocument` and a `printDialog` panel and use this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

which is a reference for `printDocument` and then just simply do this for printing your document:

```
prindDialog1.document = yourprintDocument;
```

And everything will go fine.

But, if you want to print something like pdf files you should use a `pdfWriter` in order to invoke the `adobePdf` process and print via that.

And the other option is using the `PrintPage` event of `printDocument` component which will fire on every page and by using the Graphic library you can Draw everything on each page!

Answer (score 1):

I suppose, if your printer was detect in your computer, you can use the PrinterSettings 's class for send your file to your printer... please read [msdn documentation for printerSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.drawing.printing.printersettings%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

But, when you said "network" is a local network? other network?